# Customizing SharePoint search scope dropdown to radio button

Tags: search, scope

I want to change the default scope dropdown to Radio buttons.
Any ideas on how to achieve it.

Comment: Need a bit more information: What version of SharePoint are you using? Are you going to list the options on a particular page? The search scopes show in MANY different places, where SPECIFICALLY are you talking about (or what control name are you talking about)?

Comment: I am using SP 2010. I want to customize the search scope showed in search center home page where we have the option to filter the scope using dropdown, which comes along with the search box.

Comment: I have modified the search scope to radio button from dropdown following  the below site [link](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/03/09/how-to-build-a-custom-advanced-search-control-for-enterprise-search.aspx). i wanted to know how to get the scopes in radio button dynamically as in future we will add more scopes and everytime the code cannot be changed as i have hardcoded the values for the radio button.

Comment: Hey can you help in the implementation of the same?

Answer (score 1):

In 2010 I would write my own control. You can subclass the existing control and then register it as a delegate, or simply replace the existing control on the page. In 2013 this is easier with control templates.